# Xamarin Android AOT Compilation Availability in AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops, xamarin.android

The documentation around the AOT compilation feature of Xamarin Android states that it is only available when using Enterprise additions of Visual Studio. What does this means for AzureDevops build pipelines if the feature is enabled?

Presumably the build agents don't use an Enterprise addition of the Visual Studio build tools so does this mean a build produced via AzureDevops cannot have the AOT feature enabled? If this is true the feature seems of limited use when using AzureDevops as you won't be able to have it enabled for release builds coming from your build pipelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Build Agent "Windows latest" does have VS 2019 Enterprise installed. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for a link to the List with all included software.
In addition, last time I tried that out I had to manually install the Android NDK. I used a command line step with this:

```
 C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager "ndk-bundle"
```

Although it might well be that this changed meanwhile since it is listed in the included software.

Comment: Thanks, what I'm not sure about is what subscription level is the VS install and is it acceptable to enable the AOT feature from within AzureDevops.

Comment: Oh, seems I accidentally edited the "Enterprise" out. But yeah, as you can see under the link in my answer (or here: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#visual-studio-enterprise-2019) it is VS Enterprise

Comment: Ah ok yeah I missed that as well.